# gateway between JMS and mobile apps?

Tags: firebase, glassfish, jms, mqtt, mbaas

In general terms what's the [most](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3957665/262852) pragmatic approach towards creating a gateway between a `JMS` queue and, specifically, `ios`?  Ideally, the iPhone app would simply listen to the queue, but that doesn't [look](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5032124/262852) to be an option.

So, to make an event driven program it makes sense to then turn towards some sort of `mBaaS`?  Specifically:  `firebase`.

The conclusion I'm left with is to listen to the queue and then push those messages to `firebase`.  That's a reasonable approach to get these platforms communicating.  (At least for the iPhone to listen, if not also to publish.)

***Not*** looking to use [Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563168/262852).